# Returning the result of an AJAX Call in Codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I want to implement AJAX in my codeigniter application, but I am clueless on how to return the data to the view. Also I'm not very sure if I am executing the controller in the right manner. However, the AJAX call is a success as I get the message below

```
XHR finished loading:

$.ajax({    
              type: "post",
              cache:true,   
              url: "<?php echo site_url('getrates/index'); ?>",              
            }).done(function() {
              $("#ajax-message").html("Success");
            });
```

Here is the controller

```
class Getrates extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('getrates');
}

public function index()
{
     $username = $sess_array['username'];

     $data['rates'] = $this->getrates->index($username); 

     $this->load->view('dashboard', $data['rates']);         

}
```

}

And the Model

```
class Rates extends CI_Model {


public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();


}

function index($user) {

    $username = $user;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tarrifs WHERE username = ? "; 

    $rates = $this->db->query($sql, array(1, $username));

    return $rates;

}
```

}

Comment: instead return, you should print your data.

Comment: printing didn't help.

Comment: `return $this->load->view('dashboard, $data['rates']);` try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please put ajax response in message section, try this way

```
 $.ajax({    
                  type: "post",
                  cache:true,   
                  url: "<?php echo site_url('getrates/index'); ?>",              
                }).done(function(data) {
                  $("#ajax-message").html(data);
                });
```

In model

```
function index($user) {

    $username = $user;

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tarrifs WHERE username = {$username} "; 

    $rates = $this->db->query($sql);

    return $rates->row_array(); // return single row in array

}
```

And controller please try this way

```
public function index()
{
     $username = $sess_array['username'];

     $data['rates'] = $this->getrates->index($username); 
     // true parameter return view data
     echo $this->load->view('dashboard', $data['rates'], true);       
     die();

}
```

Comment: I got a Parse Error, I guess its something to do with my controller or model code

Comment: @Bazinga777, i have updated code, hope it would helpful

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that $.ajax is not retrieving any data coming from your controller, maybe because its pointing to the wrong url, maybe you should replace it with this instead:

```
url: "<?php echo site_url('getrates'); ?>
```

referring to how [codeigniter controllers works](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html), and instead of loading a view in that controller try echoing the value your receiving from your model instead, so your $.ajax wouldn't retrieve the whole view your controller is rendering, ie:

```
$username = $sess_array['username'];
$data['rates'] = $this->getrates->index($username);
echo json_encode($data['rates']) or return json_encode($data['rates'])
```

which one works to you the best, then change the id of your placeholder that exist in a certain page, then load that controller instead of the one your loading right now:

```
$("#a-different-page").html(data);
```

As to your model I'm not sure if it's incorrect to name a model function as "index" but I would suggest naming it with a more appropriate one like function model_genrates(){}

hope it helps, cheers!